# Why is my csv data altered by casting it as a list in another variable?

Tags: python, csv

If I run

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("input2.csv"))
for row in input_file:
      print (row)
```

It works as I would expect and prints out the csv file. However if I add the line

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("input2.csv"))
data = list(input_file)
for row in input_file:
      print (row)
```

It now does not print anything out. Why does assigning the data variable to a list of the input_file, alter input_file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input_file` is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#iterators). Your call `list(input_file)` exhausts it.
That is, it iterates through all lines and *yields* each one of them to `data`, after which it has no more lines to yield.

Try:

```
data = list(input_file)
for row in data:
      print (row)
```

to see that the data is still there.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense.